# Custom schema for Instagram redirect_uri

Tags: java, android, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to integrate Instagram in android application and want to use custom schema, like - **sociallogin://authorize**

[image]

Is there a way to use **non-http/https** redirect_uri in Instagram developer portal?

Comment: not supported currently

Comment: So currently we can use only Webview for Instagram integration. Right? Can't we directly authenticate through Instagram app?

Comment: thats correct, popup a webview and redirect to some dumy url and grab access_token from url hash param via webview callback/delegate method

Comment: Okay :)

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems instagram removed the support for custom URI a few months ago.

Even though you now need to provide an URI starting with http or https you can still provide a rubbish one and implement the proper mechanism in your app to handle it.